# Calculate the new x and y coordinate of the extent after rotating the map in MapViewer ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, coordinates, arcgis-online, mathematics

I need to add a symbol to the lower left corner of the map, so every time I rotate the map, I need to calculate the new coordinate of this symbol (which is the new map extent of the lower left corner).

This is the image explaining my problem:
[image: Calculating new coordinate after rotating the map]

- The black box shows the original map view with rotation = 0, where I know the value of X and Y (the black dot)
- The blue box shows the map view after rotated 35 degree counter-clockwise, where I need to calculate the value of X' and Y' (the blue dot)

I have tried this formula, but I did not get the correct coordinate.

```
x' = x * cos(θ) - y * sin(θ)
y' = x * sin(θ) + y * cos(θ)
```

Can someone point out a correct formula to use in this case?

Comment: You can't do Cartesian math on angular units (decimal degrees). You can use `arcpy.PointGeometry` of the centroid and corners to compute `angleAndDistanceTo`, then change the bearing with `pointFromAngleAndDistance`, though at that scale, the result is unlikely to be a rectangle.

Comment: You are rotating around center of rectangle. So subtract it's coordinates from corner ones. Apply formula. Add centre coordinates.

Comment: @FelixIP How do I mark your comment as the answer? Thank you so much, it worked!

Comment: It's perfectly fine to self-answer.  So, do it please and mark as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer by @FelixIP:

1. Calculate center coordinate (x_cent, y_cent)
2. Subtract the center coordinate from current corner's (x - x_cent, y-y_cent)
3. Apply the formula above
4. Add the center coordinate back (x' + x_cent, y' + y_cent)